# Optimising MySQL Script - Users, user addresses and countries in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I'm currently trying to optimise a heavy script (query) that is taking **4.9452 seconds** to run. Then there is a PHP while loop that sets some arrays up based on whats returned, however that is another issue.

**EDIT - The users table is ~9000 rows, the user_address table is ~3000 rows, with shop_countries ~200 rows.**

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
            users.id AS user_id,
            users.unique_code AS user_unique_code,
            users.first_name AS user_first_name,
            users.surname AS user_surname,
            users.organisation AS user_organisation,
            users.telephone AS user_telephone,
            users.email AS user_email,
            users.password AS user_password,
            users.newsletter AS user_newsletter,

            user_address.id AS user_address_id,
            user_address.user_id AS user_address_user_id,
            user_address.nickname AS user_address_nickname,
            user_address.address_type AS user_address_type,
            user_address.address_line_1 AS user_address_line_1,
            user_address.address_line_2 AS user_address_line_2,
            user_address.address_line_3 AS user_address_line_3,
            user_address.city AS user_address_city,
            user_address.postcode AS user_address_postcode,
            user_address.country_id AS user_address_country_id,

            shop_countries.printable_name 
            FROM users 
            LEFT JOIN user_address ON users.id = user_address.user_id
            LEFT JOIN shop_countries ON shop_countries.id = user_address.country_id
            WHERE (users.surname != "" OR users.first_name != "")
            ORDER BY users.surname ASC, users.first_name ASC;
```

I need to select all users regardless of if they have an address assigned to them, and then attach any countries if there **IS** an address available.

**Here is the result of EXPLAIN EXTENDED**

http://imgur.com/a/UlVX3

So far, it seems that if I were to change the `LEFT JOIN` to just `JOIN` then the query executes in less than a second. With the problem being I need all the users regardless of if they have an address.

**PHP Script**

For anyone wanting to see the corresponding PHP function for reference on my design, please see below:

```
function getAllUsersWithAddresses() {

$customers = array();

$sql = 'SELECT 
            users.id AS user_id,
            users.unique_code AS user_unique_code,
            users.first_name AS user_first_name,
            users.surname AS user_surname,
            users.organisation AS user_organisation,
            users.telephone AS user_telephone,
            users.email AS user_email,
            users.password AS user_password,
            users.newsletter AS user_newsletter,

            user_address.id AS user_address_id,
            user_address.user_id AS user_address_user_id,
            user_address.nickname AS user_address_nickname,
            user_address.address_type AS user_address_type,
            user_address.address_line_1 AS user_address_line_1,
            user_address.address_line_2 AS user_address_line_2,
            user_address.address_line_3 AS user_address_line_3,
            user_address.city AS user_address_city,
            user_address.postcode AS user_address_postcode,
            user_address.country_id AS user_address_country_id,

            shop_countries.printable_name 
            FROM users 
            LEFT JOIN user_address ON users.id = user_address.user_id LEFT JOIN shop_countries ON shop_countries.id = user_address.country_id WHERE (users.surname != "" OR users.first_name != "") ORDER BY users.surname ASC, users.first_name ASC;';

$users_query = mysql_query($sql);

$customers = array();

while($row = getData($users_query)) {
    if(!isset($customers[$row['user_id']])) {
        $customers[$row['user_id']] = array(
            'id'           => $row['user_id'],
            'unique_code'  => $row['user_unique_code'],
            'first_name'   => $row['user_first_name'],
            'surname'      => $row['user_surname'],
            'organisation' => $row['user_organisation'],
            'telephone'    => $row['user_telephone'],
            'email'        => $row['user_email'],
            'password'     => $row['user_password'],
            'newsletter'   => $row['user_newsletter']
        );
    }

    if(isset($customers[$row['user_id']]) && !empty($row['user_address_type'])) {
        $customers[$row['user_id']]['addresses'][$row['user_address_type']][] = array(
            'id' => $row['user_address_id'],
            'user_id' => $row['user_address_user_id'],
            'nickname' => $row['user_address_nickname'],
            'address_type' => $row['user_address_type'],
            'address_line_1' => $row['user_address_line_1'],
            'address_line_2' => $row['user_address_line_2'],
            'address_line_3' => $row['user_address_line_3'],
            'city' => $row['user_address_city'],
            'postcode' => $row['user_address_postcode']
        );
    } else {
        $customers[$row['user_id']]['addresses'] = array();
    }
}

return $customers;
}
```

Comment: Where is trhe heavy script?

Comment: @bub the MySQL query is taking ~5 seconds to load.

Comment: What did EXPLAIN say to you? Have you set the proper indexes?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/UlVX3 - this is EXPLAIN. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: It seems you didnt set any indexes

Comment: What would be best to set indexes on, based on my query?

Comment: Take a look at [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: @bub Thanks. Got it to work by adding an index to the user_address.user_id field. Now runs at ~ 0.0468seconds

Comment: make sure all your ids in the three tables are indexed

Comment: You welcome. What a big difference now ;) The magic of indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index for your foreign ids

- user_address.user_id
- user_address.country_id

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your explain plan - it would have been helpful if you had posted it in your question. However even if I could, its not much help without knowing the structure of the database - please include the create table syntax and the indexes. In an ideal world you would also include the index cardinality.

There are only two ways to make a query go faster. Reduce the number of rows the database needs to examine or make it easier for the DBMS to find the rows you want to return.

I would guess that most of the cost comes from the 2 LEFT JOINs in the query. Surely you have a complete list of countries? There aren't that many. Hence you should be able to replace the second outer join with an inner join.

> WHERE (users.surname != "" OR users.first_name != "")

Using 'OR' in a mysql query can radically change its behaviour. Do you have a lot of customers with a missing name? If it's less than 5%, then....

```
WHERE LENGTH(users.surname) AND LENGTH(users.first_name)
```

...more than 5% and indexed....

```
WHERE users.surname LIKE '_%' AND users.first_name LIKE '_%'
```

But the biggest win comes from ensuring you have indexes on primary and foreign keys.